# qooxdoo vs sproutcore?

Tags: qooxdoo, sproutcore

I am totally confused as too which of these two frameworks to learn. Most of the comparsons are between sproutcore and cappuccino or qooxdoo vs jquery. If the criteria is a JS framework that:
1. builds desktop like web apps 
2. offers the ability to also build web apps for smartphones.

Which would you choose between these two frameworks and why?

Regards

Answer (score 9):

KKj, I'd suggest you take some time to make yourself familiar with each framework. Depending on what kind of apps you like to create, I could well imagine that both are up for the task. IMHO qooxodo is the more comprehensive and mature framework, but of course being involved in qooxdoo I'm biased.

In general, creating desktop-style apps as well as web apps for smartphones are two requirements that aren't easily covered by a single framework. Usually there are tradeoffs in that you cannot just use *all* the features a framework offers for complex desktop apps now in a mobile environment. qooxdoo and Sproutcore have started to look into incorporating mobile-specific features, but I'd say for them (and others) there is still quite some way to go. Targeting fully featured desktop applications, you could start right away:

- [Try the qooxdoo hello world](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/helloworld)
- [Learn from the qooxdoo app tutorial](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1#tutorial)

There is an (somewhat older) article about [Popular JavaScript Framework Libraries: qooxdoo and SproutCore](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg23/index.html) that you might find useful. qooxdoo is also at the [Comparison of JavaScript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) at Wikipedia, Sproutcore unfortunately isn't. If you have some more specific questions, feel free to ask the qooxdoo community via the [qooxdoo mailinglist](http://qooxdoo.org/community#mailing_lists). HTH.

Comment: the setup of qooxdoo is a cinche on windows. I went through some hell trying to use cappuccino(originally my choice) but had to settle for SC after a while. However, i had to abandon it after 24 hours.
I then went to QXD and OMG IMHO it rocks. I know what the code says and can easily follow. Though I wanted to use cappuccino, Im glad I found QXD

Answer (score 3):

From a beginners point of view, Qooxdoo may be easier to get started with because its documentation is much better. Qooxdoo is fully mature and very comprehensive in comparision to sproutcore which is although evolving rapidly but not as mature as qooxdoo.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like SproutCore would be the perfect candidate for what you want to build, though I expect at this point you've already made a decision. The latest versions of SC fully support touch events and are being successfully used on mobile devices. We've been putting a lot of effort into providing native level performance and interactivity on devices like the iPad. Furthermore, you even have the option of actually making your app run like a native app with the help of tools like PhoneGap. If you have more questions, visit the IRC chat room at #sproutcore or check out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com.